# Responsive mobile navbar links wont work on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an issue with the responsive sidebar nav links(anchor tags) won't  click
Here is the part of the HTML code

```
 <!-- Nav -->
       <nav class="main-nav">
           <img src="img/logo-dark-transparent.png" alt="AS Logo" class="logo">
           <ul class="main-menu">
               <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
               <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
               <li><a href="#contact">Contact Me</a></li>
           </ul>
          ....
       </nav>
```

The main CSS code for navbar is here

```
.main-nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    z-index: 1;
    /* font-size: 1.5em; */
    font-size: clamp(.5rem, .8vw + 1rem, 1.5rem);
}

.main-nav .logo{
    width: 110px;
}

.main-nav ul{
    display: flex;
}

.main-nav .main-menu li{
    padding: 0 2em;
}
.main-nav .main-menu li a{
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
.main-nav .main-menu li a:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px solid var(--text-color);
}
```

The CSS code for side nav is

```
@media(max-width:700px){
   .container{
    overflow-x: hidden;
   }

    section{
        height: auto;
    }
    /* Navbar */
    .menu-btn{
        display: block;
    }

    .menu-btn:hover{
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    
    .main-nav ul.main-menu{
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: var(--bg-color);
        filter: brightness(0.85);
        width: 60%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0.9;
        padding: 30px;
        transform: translateX(-500px);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease;
    }

    .main-nav ul.main-menu.show{
        transform: translateX(-20px);
    }

    .main-nav ul.main-menu li{
        padding: 20px;
    }
    .main-nav ul.main-menu li:first-child{
        margin-top: 2rem;
    }
    .main-nav ul.right-menu{
        margin-right: 60px;
    }
```

But the show class is toggled dynamically by JS code below

```
//Toggle Menu
const mainMenu = document.querySelector('.main-menu');
document.querySelector('.menu-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    mainMenu.classList.toggle('show');
})
```

Also, I wanted to achieve smooth scrolling which works on desktop version but doesn't in the mobile sidebar menu using this JS code snippet

```
//Vanilla JS Smooth Scroll
document.querySelectorAll('.main-menu a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
          
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    });
});
```

I have been debugging for hours with no success, any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Putting your code in a snippet I can click all links correctly. Also, the second part of your question makes no sense as there's no .menu-btn element in your HTML code.

Comment: Yeah i forgot to add it in my snippet but its there just fontawesome icon positioned absolute

Comment: Yeah but the links won't work on mobile device

Answer (score 0):

Add `!important` in your CSS code

```
.menu-btn { display: block !important;  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but they do display block on mobile but cant click them

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the id of div you want to scroll with do not match the link(href) addresses.You need to make sure this. Also, you can do a null check in the JavaScript code as follows.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.main-menu a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var elmnt = document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href'));
        if(elmnt != null) {
          elmnt.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth'
          });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but the id is not an issue because it works on desktop versions

Comment: Also, i tried your code snippet but same result